# parse xml - get youtube description from videos in playlist

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Im trying to get the description of a youtube video from a youtube playlist.

the xml playlist looks something like this:

```
<entry gd:etag="W/&quot;YhjhqeyM.&quot;">
  <title>My Title</title>
  <media:group>
    <media:description type="plain">My description</media:description>
  </media:group>
</entry>
.
.
.
...multiple entry elements
```

I'm looping through the multiple entries and getting the title like so:

```
var x = (from e in xmlFeed.Root.Elements().Where(n => n.Name.LocalName == "entry") select e);


     foreach (XElement element in x)
      {
          title = element.Elements().Where(n => n.Name.LocalName == "title").FirstOrDefault().Value;
          description = //??;
      }
```

How can i get the description given the above format?

Thanks

Comment: can you give a sample url where you're getting the XML?

Comment: @Duane, something like this: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/63F0C78739B09958?v=2

Answer (score 0):

```
description = element.Descendants(XName.Get("description")).First().Value();
```

Comment: this gives an error: Non-invocable member 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Value' cannot be used like a method

Comment: 'Value' is a property it should be invoked without (). description = element.Descendants(XName.Get("description")).First().Value;

Answer (score 0):

This does it, it's up to you how you're loading in your doc though. I've read it in with a `HttpWebRequest`/`StreamReader` in this case:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(requestData("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/63F0C78739B09958?v=2"));

var node = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("media:description").ToList();

foreach (var description in node)
{
     Response.Write(string.Format("Description: {0}\n",description.InnerText.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: Probably... But it makes things a lot easier. Is there a reason you don't want to use it?

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/63F0C78739B09958?v=2");
XNamespace media = XNamespace.Get("http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/");
var descs = xDoc.Descendants(media + "description")
    .Select(d => d.Value)
    .ToArray();
```